# Downloading data from another site

Tags: scrape

I would like the data from https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/group/684 for this data:

[SCREENSHOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbci4.png)

and then display them on my website but I don't even know where to start. If anyone could help me, I would be grateful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

would like to download data from https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/group/684
I was able to make such a code in CURL `<?php

$lurl=get_fcontent("https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/");
print_r($lurl[0]);

function get_fcontent( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 ) {
$url = str_replace( "&", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

```
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv: 31.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 31.0");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302) {
    ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv: 31.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 31.0");

    if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) ) {
        foreach( $headers as $value ) {
            if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
        }
    }
}

if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value) ) && $javascript_loop < 5) {
    return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
} else {
    return array( $content, $response );
}
```

}

```
?>`, it works correctly on other websites and on https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/group/684 such an error pops up from cloudflare, what should I do?
```

[ERROR SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl4md.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can just look for the the API's other than downloading. I guess using API's will be the best option here

Comment: The site does not have an api